# How to change local settings (separate numbers with a comma when saving in Excel) in Tabulator (sheetjs)

Tags: excel, tabulator, sheetjs

I began to actively use the Tabulator library, which in turn uses the well-known Sheetjs library. But when uploading to Excel, I get a fractional separator in the form of a dot, but in our locale commas are used for this.
For example, I get the following number from the database in the JSON table: 1234567.87654, but I need it to be 1234567,87654. In the table view of the tabulator and json, I can change the comma delimiter format, however, when saving to Excel via sheetjs, I get a text column instead of a numeric one.
Please tell me how to separate the numbers with a comma when saving in Excel, so that the format of the numbers is separated by commas?

I tried "Column Calculations" in the tabulator - it's strange that if you do not change the default delimiter format, when unloading, the columns are delimited by a period, and the rows with total values are separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the Number format at Excel level, this can be done by modifying the workbook with SheetJS methods during tabulator export using `documentProcessing` callback. Combined with `accessorDownload` option to convert the number to the format you need.

You can loop thru tabulator data and set the format to each cell of the column you need, based on SheetJS number formats (https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/csf/features/nf#currency).

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/w2amk8dc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Timur's code is good, but it doesn't work completely for me. Here's my code:

```
document.getElementById("download-xlsx").addEventListener("click", function(){
        table.setLocale("ru-ru");            
        const sheetName = 'EQ_VYP'
        table.download('xlsx', 'eq_vyp.xlsx', {
            sheetName: sheetName,
            documentProcessing: (workbook) => {
            const rows = table.getRows()

            rows.forEach((row, index) => {                    
                const cell_L = 'L' + (index + 2)                    
                workbook.Sheets[sheetName][cell_L].z = '_-* # ##0_-;-* # ##0_-;_-* "-"_-;_-@_-'   
                const cell_N = 'N' + (index + 2)                    
                workbook.Sheets[sheetName][cell_N].z = '_-* # ##0 ₽_-;-* # ##0 ₽_-;_-* "-" ₽_-;_-@_-'                     
                const cell_M = 'M' + (index + 2)                    
                workbook.Sheets[sheetName][cell_M].z = '"$"#.##0,00_);\\("$"#.##0,00\\)'
                const cell_O = 'O' + (index + 2)                    
                workbook.Sheets[sheetName][cell_O].z = '_-* # ##0_);\\("$"# ##0,00\\)'
            })

            return workbook
            }
        })
    });
```

When the Excel file is saved in the cell properties, you can see that the format is applied, but the cell itself has not changed. Only if I double click on a cell and press enter the format changes to the correct one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).